# Laptop showing up black screen

Tags: laptop-repair, charger, dell-studio

I have a Dell Studio 17 laptop. Once I forgot its charger and charged it with the charger from Dell Inspiron 1525. After using this charger for several times, my laptop is not turning on despite using its original chargers or any other charger. Only the keyboard lights turn on when I try to power it up. Screen remains black and after some time the laptop heats up. I don't know what to do. Please provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

Dell chargers for these two laptops are compatible. It is likely that your problem does not have anything in common with charger. If you don't feel very confident about laptop repairs (and you don't seem to), then take it to the service. This is your best bet. Getting answers on this website and trying to repair the machine yourself without sufficient knowledge will only run you into more problems.
Good luck